# How to check current route in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, universal-cli

For basic Angular2 it is possible to check current route like this:

```
this.subscription = router.events.subscribe((val: any) => {

});
```

But there is problem when use Angular Universal on server side...

Any solution for this?

Comment: Have you find any solution yet?